# In Far Cry 4, how do I spot alarm boxes in hostile outposts?

Tags: far-cry-4

So yesterday I played some more FC4 and tried to capture an outpost without being spotted. I almost succeeded but there was one enemy I didn't spot, who saw me and called reinforcements. I retried it after I took over the camp forcefully.

On retrying the same outpost a few times I finally spotted what the alarm boxes look like and took it out from a distance. (though the sound of the explosion of the alarm box warned the guards).

I see in the legend of the world map there is an icon for those alarm boxes. I have never seen that icon on the map yet, even when fully zoomed in.
When hovering over the outpost icon on the map, it says how many alarms there are.
**How do I spot these alarm boxes?**

Comment: I don't think you can mark them if that's what you mean. You just need to scout the outpost and shoot the ones that won't alert anyone nearby, and sneak towards the others to disable them. Or you just kill everyone before they manage to reach one of the boxes.

Comment: Yes that and also how I can easily find them. The one that I saw was yellow. Are they always yellow? Are they always attached to a pole like the one I saw? Are they usually near the middle or edges? Are they guarded? Those sorts of things would help a lot.

Comment: In Far Cry 3 they were on the minimap. Normally they're big boxes on polls or walls. You can go melee and destroy them with your knife or you shoot on them using a silent weapon

Comment: @JonasDralle Interacting with alarm boxes is far better than striking it with your knife. They both require he same range, but patrols can't hear you interact with the alarm, while smashing it to bits with your knife would send them running over.

Comment: *Nixon voice* Now I know something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On the Map**

Alarm boxes appear on your minimap rather than the main map. Unfortunately when you're attacking an outpost the minimap's zoom level may not let you see some or all of the boxes.

An alarm box appears as an icon of a white speaker facing to the right with a white arc representing its sound. Once triggered it will change, pulsing pink or yellow if I recall correctly (someone who has FC4 installed, please edit). You can see three alarm box icons [in this image](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UsXE9okYWlw/maxresdefault.jpg).

**In the World**

But even when I can see one of the speaker icons, I find it only generally helpful to show me the right direction. It's much better to scout their locations in the real world, ideally from above the outpost or fortress.

Alarm boxes are almost always mounted on tall poles with conical speakers near the top. Learn to look for the speakers. You can see examples [here](http://guides.gamepressure.com/farcry4/gfx/word/3582079.jpg) above the crossbow, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ow2N.png)... well, it's hard to miss in this image.

They can appear anywhere in the outpost, though they're not as often right on the perimeter. They aren't always directly guarded, though most at least have guards that walk past them occasionally.

**Taking Them Out**

You can take the box out from a distance with a rifle, arrow, or even a throwing knife. Up close you can shoot them or simply interact with them for stealth.

If guards are near one when you take it out they might cry out, but that doesn't count as a detection. If they're not near the box when you take it out, a guard patrolling near it in the future is likely to yell something about the box being broken. It's fun to hear them yell about it when they run to trigger a broken box—though of course, it's more fun to cap the outpost without being detected.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played for a while now, but IIRC look for the poles with the loudspeakers; they each should have a yellowish light on top to mark them. That pole either has the box or a wire that you can follow back to the box that sets off that alarm.

As for placement, I've seen them on the edges and near the middle so there doesn't seem to be a pattern. And as the guards walk around randomly, some will be guarded and some not at different times. Use a takedown on any guards near the boxes and interact with the box to silently disable it.